# target=_blank not working in Flexslider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I've added a text area to each slide, an external link is called using a custom field, but using `target="_blank"` doesn't open links in a new window - it just loads the link in the same window.  `target=_blank` works fine on the same page outside of Flexslider, so I'm assuming the link is getting interfered with by Flexslider, but I'm not sure how.

I've checked the [FlexSlider properties](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) but I don't see anything regarding this issue.  Here is the code I'm using for the flexslider:

```
<div class="flexslider">    
<ul class="slides">
    <?php  
        query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'slides',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ));
        if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    ?>          
    <li>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('slide');
        } ?>

        <div class="banner-text">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <a href="<?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_slide_link', true ); echo $text; ?>" target="_blank">Learn More &rarr;</a>
        </div>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 161 of the [source code](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L160), a `preventDefault` is added to each slide when it is clicked.

You would have to find a way of circumventing that or edit the source code to match the required functionality.

Comment: Thanks StephenRios, I'm looking into this now.